# mvc and castle windsor - registratrion events

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, castle-windsor

When I register components with castle's container in my app startup - should I see the registered classes being instantiated when I debug.

```
_container = new WindsorContainer();
_container.Register(
  AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<ValidationPatterns>()
                    .BasedOn(typeof(IValidator<>))
                    .WithService.Base());
```

Should I be able to see each of the relevant classes that fit the types i.e. inherit from IValidator, being instantiated?

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windsor instantiates components *on-demand*, i.e. when they're resolved and no suitable instance (according to component lifestyle) is found. They're *not* instantiated at registration-time.

See "[How components are created](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.How-components-are-created.ashx)" for a more thorough explanation of the process.

Comment: Ok, so only instantiated when they are needed?

Comment: If you want them to be instantiated eagerly make them startable (see "Startable Facility" section in Windsor's documentation)